# jQuery don't find any loaded elements after jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, find

jQuery don't find any loaded elements after jQuery.load()

```
function makeEditForTextBox(textbox,editor) {
    editor.load("templates/textbox-edit.html");
    editor.find("#edit-save").click(function(event) { //here jQuery can't find #edit-save button
       id=editor.find("#edit-id-name").text();
       alert(id);
       textbox.find("input").attr("id",id);
       textbox.find("input").attr("name",id);
       textbox.find("input").attr("placeholder",editor.find("#edit-placeholder").text());
       textbox.find("label").text(editor.find("#edit-label-text"));
       alert("save clicked");
   });
   alert("loaded");
}
```

textbox-edit.html:

```
<label>ID/Name</label>
<input type="text" id="edit-id-name">
<label>Label Text</label>
<input type="text" id="edit-label-text">
<label>Placeholder</label>
<input type="text" id="edit-placeholder">
<label>Help Text</label>
<input type="text" id="edit-help-text">
<button id="edit-save">Save</button>
<button id="edit-cancel">Cancel</button>
```

I have loaded elements in browser, but jQuery can't find them.

Comment: You could use `load()` callback or better in your case, delegate click event  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` is running immediately after `load()` **starts**, not when `load()` finishes. You can put that code in the callback so that it's executed when load has completed.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )

```
function makeEditForTextBox(textbox,editor) {
    editor.load("templates/textbox-edit.html", function(){
        editor.find("#edit-save").click(function(event) { 
           id=editor.find("#edit-id-name").text();
           alert(id);
           textbox.find("input").attr("id",id);
           textbox.find("input").attr("name",id);
           textbox.find("input").attr("placeholder",editor.find("#edit-placeholder").text());
           textbox.find("label").text(editor.find("#edit-label-text"));
           alert("save clicked");
       });
    });
}
```